# data not transferring from Textbox to query

Tags: c#, database, textbox

I am creating a desktop application in C# where my code is:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clsFunctions.recordExist("SELECT AtNumConstructorID, TxtConstructorName AS Fullname FROM tblConstructorDetails WHERE txtUserName = '" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND TxtPassword LIKE '" + txtPassword.Text + "' ", "tblConstructorDetails") == true)
    {
        clsVariables._sTimeLogin = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();//recording the time of login in the CES
        long totalRow = 0;
        //Set the Data Adapter
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select AtNumConstructorID, TxtConstructorName AS Fullname, tblConstructorDetails.txtUserName FROM tblConstructorDetails WHERE txtUserName =" + txtUserName.Text, clsConnections._olbedbCN);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(); // creating a dataset to enter the values in the dataadapter
        da.Fill(ds, "tblConstructorDetails");
        totalRow = ds.Tables["tblConstructorDetails"].Rows.Count - 1;
        clsVariables._sContId = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["tblConstructorDetails"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(0));
        clsVariables._sConstructor = ds.Tables["tblConstructorDetails"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        clsVariables._sUserID = ds.Tables["tblConstructorDetails"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        clsUserLogs.RecordLogin(clsVariables._sTimeLogin, clsVariables._sContId);
        clsApplication._boolAPP_CONNECTED = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Note: clsFunctions : A class where all the common functions are written
       recordexist : function, which returns true if a record is available.

For recordexist, I am providing a query. the data from the textbox is not be transferred to the query and I can make out, why it is happening.

Comment: You are doing a `like` comparison on the password? WTF? If someone enters a `%` they will be able to login as any user they wish.

Comment: this code is wrong for so many reasons. no parameterized sql, no dataset null checking, etc etc

Comment: @klausbyskov : that was just a demo code which i tried if it could run with % characters....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the password case insensitive use this:

```
UPPER(TxtPassword) = UPPER('" + txtPassword.Text + "') "
```

*Ignore below did not see it was not a webapp*

The problem must be in the you aspx page or how you reference that page.  Please post the aspx  too.

My guess is you are not hooking the event in right or not declaring txtUserName right.

Comment: It's a desktop application, so basically the problem must be that he's referencing the wrong text boxes (or that nothing has been entered)

Comment: @sohil : there is no way to know without seeing the rest of your code for the form.